# How many fences are necessary to support multiple frames in flight each using multiple command queues in DirectX 12?

Tags: directx-12

Let's say I have a frame, that uses 2 copy queues, 1 graphics and 1 compute queue in order:

**1)** Upload data from CPU to GPU using 1st copy queue at the beginning of the frame (mesh vertices and such). That will be `ExecuteCommandLists` on 1st copy queue then `SignalFence`.

**2)** Build a ray tracing acceleration structure on async compute queue. `WaitFence` to wait for data we just uploaded, then `ExecuteCommandLists` to build accel. structure, then `SignalFence`.

**3)** `WaitFence` on graphics queue to wait for AS build then `ExecuteCommandLists` to render the frame. Then issue another `SignalFence`

**4)** `WaitFence` then `ExecuteCommandLists` on 2nd copy queue to perform data readback (GPU -> CPU), let's say to get terrain and physics back to the CPU. Then we call the final `SignalFence` for the frame.

Now, I want to have 3 frames buffered at all times to avoid CPU/GPU bubbles when no work is performed.

*What would be the correct fence setup to achieve this?*

So far I have implemented 2 variants 1 of which should work (unless I'm completely wrong) but it doesn't, and second works, but I'm not sure why. Please help me figure it out.

**1)** Have **2** fences (**A** and **B**) for all of the frames and queues:

For 1st frame:

```
CopyQueue1.ExecuteCommands();
CopyQueue1.SignalFence(A, 1);

AsyncComputeQueue.Wait(A, 1);
AsyncComputeQueue.ExecuteCommands();
AsyncComputeQueue.Signal(A, 2);

GraphicsQueue.Wait(A, 2);
GraphicsQueue.ExecuteCommands();
GraphicsQueue.Signal(A, 3);

CopyQueue2.Wait(A, 3);
CopyQueue2.ExecuteCommands();
CopyQueue2.Signal(B, 1);
```

Same thing for the next frames except that values for **A** and **B** will be incremented: 3, 4, 5 and 6, 7, 8 for **A** in frame 2 and 3, and values 2, 3 in frames 2 and 3 respectively for **B**.

At the end of render loop I perform a check to keep maximum of 3 frames in flight:

```
if (CurrentFrameBValue - B.SignalledValue() >= 3)
{
    StallCurrentCPUThread();
} 

ReleaseCommandListsForThisFrame();
// GoToNextRenderLoop
```

This code has an issue where **B** is being signaled very quickly, I do not stall the CPU and proceed to resetting command lists for corresponding frame and get debug layer error that says I was *resetting command lists while GPU was still using them*. 
As I understand it, all work submitted to GPU is guarantied to be performed in submission order. So I expect fences to advance as follows: **A** - 1, 2, 3, then **B** to 1, then **A** to 4, 5, 6 then **B** to 2 and so forth.. Why is B signaled before all work for the frame is done?

2) Approach that's not emitting errors. Have 4 fences for each queue **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, increment their values by one each frame, as we did for **B** in case 1.

1 reason I can see for 1st case failing is that work on GPU is not really done in order I expect it, and fence **A** can be signaled in an unpredictable order, messing up dependencies, while 2nd case has separate fences for each case..

I should also note that I don't have dependencies between frames: CopyQueue1 does not depend on CopyQueue2 via fences, I ensure correctness by keeping not more then 3 frames in flight with CPU stalling shown above.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you read through the [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/user-mode-heap-synchronization) page?

Comment: Yes. Multiple times. I think I know what’s the problem. I’ll post later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was in using 1 fence for 3 different queues. Let's look at case **1**. Copy1(Frame **1**) -> AsyncCompute(Frame **1**) -> Graphics(Frame **1**) -> Copy2(Frame **1**) then Copy1(Frame **2**) -> AsyncCompute(Frame **2**) -> Graphics(Frame **2**) -> Copy2(Frame **2**) all with the same fence object but different values.

In my case, I believe, Copy1(Frame **2**) was done before AsyncCompute(Frame **1**) or even Graphics(Frame **1**), doesn't matter, because the fence value it signals is higher then anything expected in frame 1, messing up frame 1 dependencies and starting Copy2(Frame **1**) too early which led to frame finish and reset of command lists while Async and/or Graphic work was actually still running.